# How to fit webpage in moblie browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit my site in mobile browser. I'm creating two sites that are generally same in design. For the first site, it becomes auto fit in mobile browser (with 100%, height 100%). But for second site, its sidebar and content width is the same as I given.

For example: Site 1
If the width of sidebar and content is 320px, when we open the site in mobile phone which has 320px of screen width; the width of the sidebar will reduce to see the site completely.
[image]

For example: Site 2
If the width of sidebar and content is 320px, when we open the site in mobile phone which has 320px of screen width; the width of the sidebar still 320px and the full screen can be seen only sidebar.
[image]

Site 1 is what I want. I make the two site with same style. But the elements in both sites(button, textboxes, tables) are not the same style. I think, this is because of those elements. Please tell me something.
I cant use percentage because my company want in exact pixel. It's not need to be responsive. Just to maintain the scale in site 1 image as I show below.
Those images are capture in mobile browser.
**I also tried with "meta tag". It's not working.**
Here is my code simple.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 207px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #2D51A3; 
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 215px);
    min-height: calc(100vh - 3.1em);
    background-color: green;
}

<div class="app">
    <div class="sidebar">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com) to do the heavy lifting for you. It will save you loads of effort.

There are some great [tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/) on how to use it.

If you're dead set on solving this manually I'd suggest looking into [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: This is company project and they dont allow me to use bootstrap. I also use media queries. But it's not working.

Comment: Do you have <meta name="viewport" width="device-width"> inside <head></head>?

Answer (score 0):

So you will want to make the widths of your elements percentages instead of pixels, and you will want to add a media query to change the width to 100% when it hits 320px or whatever size works best. I would recommend avoiding pixels for widths when building sites that need to work on many devices.

Try this css. You can adjust the heights as needed.

```
<style>
 .sidebar {
   width: 25%;
   display: block;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   height: 200px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #2D51A3; 
 } 

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 .content {
   width: 100%;
   float: none;
 }
 .sidebar{
   width: 100%;
   float: none;
   position: static;
  }
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi Bro. I cant use percentage as my company give me with XD file with exact pixel.

Comment: Change 100% width to be 320px and use media queries.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">
```

It is used in html5 and automatically formats the webpage for any device.